# getting report from jenkins using jsonapi

Tags: json, api, jenkins

I am tring to make report from jenkins using Json API.
Report which stats below details :-

```
   Job Name     :
   No. of Build : 
   Sucessfull   :
   Failed       : 
   Aborted      :
```

I am trying to fetch all jobs which are present in jenkins instance. 
I trying with below code but getting lot of data :(

```
https://JENKSIN_URL/api/json?tree=jobs[name,color,buildable,healthReport[description,score,iconUrl],builds[changeSet[items[msg,user]]]]
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is needs more details, what you want help with and more importantly, what have you tried? The Jenkins API can be accessed at the site layer, the job layer, the build layer, etc. If there's too much data, try breaking your query into smaller chunks.

Comment: Thanks @Dave for your reply.
curretnly I am getting data from XML api like this:

JENKIN_URL/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,jobs[name,builds[number,result]]] 

which tells me about "JOBS on Dashboard----->>> JOBS inside Folder-----> Build_no  &  Result"
But not getting data about user who triggerd that buid.

Any Suggestoin please.